# iTextSharp ignores margins in newly created PDF

Tags: itext, margins

I want to parse an asp.net panel control which consists of a html table (with 4 columns) to a PD document. I have set the Pagesize to A4 and all the margins to 10.
When my pdf is created there are very big left and right margins. How can I get the left and margins wright?

This is the code used:

```
Dim strFileName = "CBB_" & lblZoekCriteria.Text & ".pdf"

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & strFileName)
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Dim sw As New StringWriter()
Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
'Me.Page.RenderControl(hw)
pnlProtestInfo.RenderControl(hw)

Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10)
Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
pdfDoc.Open()
htmlparser.Parse(sr)
pdfDoc.Close()
Response.Write(pdfDoc)
Response.[End]()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set margins you are instructing iText to **not draw** in those areas, that's it. You **are not** telling iText how wide to draw anything.

Without seeing the HTML that you're parsing I can't tell you specifically what to fix. however, below is a very basic sample that uses a table that's set to 100% width which should do what you're looking for.

Also, remember that `HTMLWorker` is old and unsupported and only a handful of the most basic of HTML and CSS tags and attributes are supported in it. Instead you are encouraged to move to  `XMLWorker`.

```
''//Output a file to the desktop
Dim strFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf")

''//Out very basic sample HTML
Dim sampleHtml = <table border="1" width="100%" align="center">
                     <tr>
                         <td>0:0</td>
                         <td>0:1</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td>1:0</td>
                         <td>1:1</td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>

''//Standard PDF setup, nothing special
Using fs As New FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)

    ''//Create our document with margins specified
    Using pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10)
        Using PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs)

            pdfDoc.Open()

            ''//Parse our HTML into the document
            Using sr As New StringReader(sampleHtml.ToString())
                Using htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
                    htmlparser.Parse(sr)
                End Using
            End Using

            pdfDoc.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```